# ruby GLI optional argument starting with a dash (-)

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, gli-gem

I wonder what the best approach would be to allow an optional argument to begin with a dash (-). I want a subcommand to accept number style arguments which should be "+42" or "-123". So from the command line I can do:

```
gliapp show -123
```

This currently leads to an error because gli thinks -123 is an unknown switch.
I know one could do

```
gliapp show -- -123
```

But I do not want the user to work around this issue.
Do I have to handle the -123 myself before passing ARGV to gli run?

here is a minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'gli'
include GLI::App
subcommand_option_handling :normal
arguments :strict

desc 'p given arg which may start with a dash (-)'
arg "number", :optional;
command :show do |c|
  c.action do |global_opts,opts,args|   
    p args.first
  end
end
exit run(ARGV)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

GLI uses `OptionParser` under the covers, and it will grab all arguments starting with a dash.  This is pretty standard UNIX.

You can use a flag to capture the value like so:

```
command :show do |c|
  c.flag :number
  c.action do |global,options,args|
    puts options[:number]
  end
end
```

and then:

```
> gliapp show --number=-123
-123
```